# Spring autowire by type with optional value

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have custom @Qualifier annotation for my components :

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface ProviderQualifier{

     ProviderType[] providerType();
}
```

ProviderType is enum :

```
public enum ProviderType{

  ADD_PROVIDER,REMOVE_PROVIDER
}
```

My components look like this :

```
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=ADD_PROVIDER)
public class AddProvider implements Providers{
   // 
}
```

finally when i want to autowire all ADD_PROVIDER components :

```
@Autowired
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=ADD_PROVIDER)
private List<Providers> addProviders;
```

This works nicely, but problem is when i have shared providers for example something like this:

```
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=ADD_PROVIDER,REMOVE_PROVIDER)
public class ValidateProvider implements Providers{
   // 
}
```

What this means is i have dedicated providers (for adding and removing) but i also have some shared providers. that i need in both add and remove flows.

As mentioned here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

> If multiple attribute values are then specified on a field or parameter to be autowired, a bean definition must match all such attribute values to be considered an autowire candidate. As an example, consider the following annotation definition:

My question is. Is there a way to configure how spring autowires beans to make this work ?

```
@Autowired
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=ADD_PROVIDER)
private List<Providers> addProviders;

@Autowired
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=REMOVE_PROVIDER)
private List<Providers> removeProviders;
```

Goal is to have ValidateProvider in both autowired lists, but that is not possible since by spring documentation autowire candidate "must match all such attribute "

I could just :

```
@Autowired
@ProviderQualifier(providerType={REMOVE_PROVIDER,ADD_PROVIDER})
private List<Providers> commonProviders;
```

And manually add them to dedicated ADD and REMOVE providers list, but this is really the last resort.

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly, but I think you could also add the type ADD_REMOVE_PROVIDER for shared provider ?

Comment: Well if i did it wouldnt get picked up by 
@Autowired
@ProviderQualifier(providerType=ADD_PROVIDER)
private List<Providers> addProviders;

Comment: OK I get it, sorry.

Comment: A possible workaround is to have two interfaces AddProvider and RemoveProvider instead of using qualifiers. Then it should be possible just to autowire by type.

Comment: Yeah solid approach. I wanted to use fancy fine tuning annotation based auto-wiring though :) thanks